# Drupal module to generate compressed xml sitemap

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

Is there any Drupal module which can generate compressed xml sitemap like sitemap.xml.gz? The problem is I have a site with a lot of pages and the generated sitemap is very big (more than 1 MB). I have "404 not found" errors in google webmaster tools for the sitemap, but when I open the address mysite.com/sitemap.xml the sitemap is displayed after more than 5 seconds. When I test my sitemap with google PageSpeed Insights it tells me to activate compression and I will reduce the data transfer for this file with 92%. 
I activated compression on Nginx and now it is compressing everything but the sitemap.  Now I am searching for a module generating compressed sitemap.
I am usung Drupal 7 with Nginx and xmlsitemap module for generating sitemap

Comment: This should be something the XML sitemap module does. It's from ages that I am not maintaining it, but I recall the module had code for that. (Clearly, it was in the Drupal 6 module, not the Drupal 7 module.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate you sitemap.xml into several sitemaps. Each of this maps will be a smaller than one big sitemap.

Go to `admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings`, in Advanced settings in Number of links in each sitemap page choose, for example, 1000 and regenerate you sitemap.

Comment: This will be the next step if I don't find a way to compress the sitemap. At the moment my sitemap is split into few sitemaps with 10 000 links each one and I am still having 404 errors in webmaster tools.